# how can I compute the following integral without using Cauchy's integral formula.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

how can I compute the following integral without using Cauchy's integral formula:

$\gamma:[0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C},$

$\gamma(t):= \exp(it)$

$$\int_{\gamma} (z-a)^{-1} dz$$

Where $a \in \mathbb{C}$ & $0<|a|<1$.

It is clear from the winding number property that the integral *should be* $2πi$.

Please give me some hint.It will help me a lot.

Comment: The integral should be $2\pi i$, you forgot that factor. View it as an integral depending on the parameter $a$. For $a = 0$ you can compute it elementarily. Then differentiate with respect to $a$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, the OP asked to evaluate the integral without using CIF.  So, it's unclear as to the meaning of that restriction.  I inferred that the OP wanted something more direct (e.g., without appeal to Cauchy's Integral Theorem and deforming the contour around $a$).  Hence, I posted a solution in which the integral is evaluated in terms of its real and imaginary parts.  I'm unclear from your comment as to the way forward you intended.   How should one evaluate $\int_\gamma \frac1{(z-a)^2}\,dz$ if one doesn't assume to know CIF, CIT, the Residue Theorem, etc.?

Comment: @MarkViola That's done with the FTC, $$\frac{1}{(z-a)^2} = -\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{z-a}\,.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes.  $\frac{d}{da}\frac{1}{z-a}=-\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{z-a}$.  So, one would need to know that in complex analysis that the FTC holds for $\frac1{z^2}$ provided that the path between the lower and upper limits of integration do not pass through the origin.  While not at all difficult to do when equipped with the prerequisite tools, it's not clear as to the OP's starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **We can evaluate the integral directly by straightforward analysis that reduces to an elementary integral from real analysis.  We now proceed accordingly.**

---

Let $z=e^{i\phi}$ and $a=|a|e^{i\theta}$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=1}\frac1{z-a}\,dz&=\int_{\theta}^{\theta+2\pi}\frac{ie^{i\phi}}{e^{i\phi}-a}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\int_{\theta}^{\theta+2\pi} \frac{ie^{i\phi}(e^{-i\phi}-a^*)}{1+|a|^2-2|a|\cos(\phi-\theta)}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\int_{\theta}^{\theta+2\pi} \frac{i-i|a|e^{i(\phi-\theta)})}{1+|a|^2-2|a|\cos(\phi-\theta)}\,d\phi\\\\
&=2i\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1-|a|\cos(\phi)}{1+|a|^2-2|a|\cos(\phi)}\,d\phi\tag1
\end{align}$$

Now evaluate the integral in $(1)$ by using, for example, the tangent half-angle substitution.

Can you finish now?